# Android equivalent of ArcGIS's AGSDynamicLayer

Tags: android, arcgis

Does anyone know if there is an Android equivalent of ArcGIS's [AGSDynamicLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/category_a_g_s_dynamic_layer_07_for_subclass_eyes_only_08.html) for iOS? I'm trying to create a map overlay image that will scale along with the rest of the map. I'm working off of [this](https://github.com/Esri/tips-and-tricks-ios/tree/master/UC2013_TipsAndTricksDemos/CustomDynamicLayer/CustomDynamicLayer) code example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DynamicLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/DynamicLayer.html) abstract class.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My problem is, I don't see any documentation on what I need to implement in the subclass. The only method it seems I need to override is `getImage(...)`. Can you point me to an example?